# Forward IP range to Kubernetes node running in Vagrant/VirtualBox

Tags: routes, kubernetes, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a 3-node Kubernetes cluster setup with Vagrant/Virtualbox. I am setting up a 4th VM that is not attached to the cluster.

I want to configure my 4th node so that it routes all traffic in the Service IP CIDR to a node on the Kubernetes cluster. The specific node doesn't matter since once traffic hits a node it will route to the correct pod as I expect.

For example, let's say I deploy a Rabbit broker on my k8s cluster behind a Service with IP `10.0.0.5` and my cluster service CIDR is `10.0.0.0/24`. On my 4th VM, I set up a python script to publish messages to `10.0.0.5`. However, `10.0.0.5` is virtual since it is a Service ClusterIP and therefore doesn't know how to route. I want to add a routing rule to automatically send `10.0.0.0/24` traffic to any of the 3 nodes in my cluster.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Although you might be able to make routing working with [route tables](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-tables.html) and [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables), I would recommend using a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) type of service so that you talk to the IP address of your nodes and not a Virtual IP that is only available within the cluster.